# How to realize Yii2 relation through string not array?

Tags: string, yii2, relation

I have a class named ChatMessage. There are 2 main columns in DB (from_user, to_user). I want to relate one of these 2 columns to User model id. How can I use a relation query that looks like this

```
public function getChattedUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), '(case when(chat_message.from_user={Yii::$app->user->id}) then chat_message.to_user else chat_message.from_user END)=user.id');
}
```

Comment: if you have constraints added in the table schema the while generating the model you should have `getFromUser` and `getToUser` relations defined in the generated model, don't they fulfill your requirement ? as what i see you are trying to get the number of users chatted with against the current logged in users

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **this is not possible**.

ActiveRecord relations are more complicated than you may think and supporting such conditions in reliable way is really complicated/impossible. The problem is that relation may be used in different contexts:

1. **Join**: `select * from chat_messages join users on users.id = chat_messages.from_user`.
2. **Lazy loading**: `select * from users where users.id = 1`.
3. **Eager loading**: `select * from users where users.id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`.

As you may see it is hard to convert your `on` condition to fit each of this three types of queries ([see this issue at GitHub](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6985)).

You may try to override `ActiveQuery` to support your condition, but much easier (and probably good enough) is to use two relations and create some helpers to make accessing these relations more convenient:

```
public function getUserFrom() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_from']);
}

public function getUserTo() {
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_to']);
}

public function getUser() {
    return Yii::$app->user->id == $this->user_from ? $this->userFrom : $this->userTo;
}
```

Trigger eager loading:

```
ChatMessage::find()->with(['userFrom', 'userTo'])->all();
```

It should be enough for simple cases. For more complex scenarios you will need to write queries manually.

---

Note that using `Yii::$app->user->id` in your model is considered as bad practice:

> In summary, models /.../
>
> - should NOT directly access request, session, or any other environmental data. These data should be injected by controllers into
>     models;

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#best-practices

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it simply by adding if statement in your relation function. Just write the `case` logic in the if statement as written below:

```
public function getChattedUser()
{
    if ($this->from_user == Yii::$app->user->id) {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'to_user']);
    }
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'from_user']);
}
```

Comment: i didnt downvoted but this does not look an optimal solution where you can use the `case` inside the relation, that must be the reason that someone downvoted, although in this yii2 community on stackoverflow , i know the guys dont downvote without any valid reason as you see in javascript forums and others, but someone should have left a comment so that you could correct your mistake

Comment: This option creates n+1 issue. I meant to make just a single Mysql query for relation