# Yii2 - hasMany relation with multiple columns

Tags: yii, yii2

I have a table `message_thread`:

```
id
sender_id
recipient_id
```

I want to declare a relation in my `User` model that will fetch all message threads as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM message_thread
WHERE sender_id = {user.id}
    OR recipent_id = {user.id}
```

I have tried the following:

```
public function getMessageThreads()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MessageThread::className(), ['sender_id' => 'id'])
        ->orWhere(['recipient_id' => 'id']);
}
```

But it generates an `AND` query. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you want in output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create regular relation in this way - Yii will not be able to map related records for eager loading, so it not supporting this. You can find some explanation int [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50334150/5812455) and related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6985).

Depending on use case you may try two approach to get something similar:

#### 1. Two regular relations and getter to simplify access

```
public function getSenderThreads() {
    return $this->hasMany(MessageThread::className(), ['sender_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getRecipientThreads() {
    return $this->hasMany(MessageThread::className(), ['recipient_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getMessageThreads() {
    return array_merge($this->senderThreads, $this->recipientThreads);
}
```

In this way you have two separate relations for sender and recipient threads, so you can use them directly with joins or eager loading. But you also have getter which will return result ofboth relations, so you can access all threads by `$model->messageThreads`.

#### 2. Fake relation

```
public function getMessageThreads()
{
    $query = MessageThread::find()
        ->andWhere([
            'or',
            ['sender_id' => $this->id],
            ['recipient_id' => $this->id],
        ]);
    $query->multiple = true;

    return $query;
}
```

This is not real relation. You will not be able to use it with eager loading or for joins, but it will fetch all user threads in one query and you still will be able to use it as regular active record relation - `$model->getMessageThreads()` will return `ActiveQuery` and `$model->messageThreads` array of models.

---

#### Why `orOnCondition()` will not work

[`orOnCondition()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#orOnCondition()-detail) and [`andOnCondition()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#andOnCondition()-detail) are for additional `ON` conditions which will always be appended to base relation condition using `AND`. So if you have relation defined like this:

```
$this->hasMany(MessageThread::className(), ['sender_id' => 'id'])
    ->orOnCondition(['recipient_id' => new Expression('id')])
    ->orOnCondition(['shared' => 1]);
```

It will generate condition like this:

```
sender_id = id AND (recipent_id = id OR shared = 1)
```

As you can see conditions defined by `orOnCondition()` are separated from condition from relation defined in `hasMany()` and they're always joined using `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

For this query

```
SELECT *
FROM message_thread
WHERE sender_id = {user.id}
    OR recipent_id = {user.id}
```

You Can use these

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query)->from("message_thread")
$query->orFilterWhere(['sender_id'=>$user_id])->orFilterWhere(['recipent_id '=>$user_id]);
```

Comment: Using `orFilterWhere()` in such cases may be tricky - if for some reason `$user_id` will be empty, condition will be omitted and this query will return all records from database. `orWhere()` should be preferable choice in most cases, `orFilterWhere()` was deigned mostly for filtering from user input.